# Deleting attribute from Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, attributes, python-3.4

I need to delete an attribute from a Dictionary object.  I am trying to do this with "del," but it is not working for me.

```
from suds.client import Client
from sys import argv

cmserver = '***my-server-host-name***'
cmport = '8443'
wsdl = 'file:///code/AXL/axlsqltoolkit/schema/10.5/AXLAPI.wsdl'
location = 'https://' + cmserver + ':' + cmport + '/axl/'
username = argv[1]
password = argv[2]

client = Client(url=wsdl,location=location, username=username, password=password)
result = client.service.getPhone(name='SEP64AE0CF74D0A')
del result['_uuid']
```

The Code fails with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "AXL-Get-Phone.py", line 27, in <module>
    del result['_uuid']
AttributeError: __delitem__
```

Sample [`print(str(result))`] output of the object I am trying to delete '_uuid' from:

```
(reply){
    return = 
        (return){
            phone = 
                (RPhone){                   
                     _uuid = "{D1246CFA-E02D-0731-826F-4B043CD529F1}"
```

Comment: Can you give the **raw** output of `print(result)`?

Comment: There is a problem in your code, result is undefined when you call `dict(result)`. Probably the object returned by client.service.getPhone isn't properly a dict, but an object providing the `__getitem__` function. In this case, it is possible that the `__delitem__` function isn't provided.

Comment: actually, I removed that line and get the same error.  The code is just this:          result = client.service.getPhone(name='SEP64AE0CF74D0A')
del result['_uuid']    I have tried forcing the object to a dictionary type, but that doesn't help any.

Comment: The output of print(result) is large.  Here is a link to download it:        https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzU-M37pyCMfT0ZIRGFBLURYclE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The output is not a dictionary. It is some weird data type.

Comment: OK, thanks for confirming that.  Any clues on how to remove the "_uuid" element from it or to convert it to a dictionary type?  I tried "dict(result)", but that doesn't work.  Do I need to strip some elements out of it to make it a dict type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you'll need to convert results into a `dict`. There is a `suds.client.Client` class method `dict` which will do this for you. See the documentation for [suds.client.Client](https://jortel.fedorapeople.org/suds/doc/suds.client.Client-class.html).

```py
result = Client.dict(client.service.getPhone(name='SEP64AE0CF74D0A'))
del result['_uuid']
```

Also, you may simply be able to delete the `_uuid` attribute, for example:

```py
result = client.service.getPhone(name='SEP64AE0CF74D0A')
del result._uuid
```

Comment: Patrick, thanks man!  The second method works:

    `result = client.service.getPhone(name='SEP64AE0CF74D0A');
    result2 = result['return']['phone'];
    del result2._uuid;`